# Using json to read from api and store values in arrays

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have a json file, containing the following:

```
array [
    object (
        string series, | Series name
        int id | Series ID
    ),
…
]
```

How can I read from this json file, and save the data in multiple arrays to use the data like $ser[seriesID][seriesname]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) like:

```
$jsonString = '[{"series":"Series Name","id":"series_1"},{"series":"Series Name","id":"series_2"}]';
$ser = json_decode($jsonString, true);
foreach ($ser as $item) {
   echo $item['series'];
   echo $item['id'];
}
```

If you now want it at you stated then you need to change the JSON format to be like this:

`{"series_1":"Series Name","series_2":"Series Name"}`

But form the dump you posted its not currently set up like that. You could also restructure it on the PHP side before usage i suppose:

```
$jsonString = '[{"series":"Series Name","id":"series_1"},{"series":"Series Name","id":"series_2"}]';
$serRaw = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$ser = array();

foreach ($serRaw as $item) {
   $id = $item['id'];
   $ser[$id] = $item['series'];
}
```